# Calculating a Function for Y when having a Function of X

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently making a video game which includes a leveling-up system and am having a bit of difficulty trying to figure out the formula I need to calculate Experience Points(X) to determine the character's level(Y).

[image]

I was able to come up with a polynomial formula to determine the sequence for X which ended up being:

[image]

*(The +1 was an error in posting)

My problem is now trying to figure out how to come up with an equation so I can calculate Y using X. I've tried to approach this by calculating a polynomial formula with X and Y swapped, but was struggling to reach an answer following this method.

I am not sure which approach would best help me reach this answer. It has been quite some time since my last math class and am having trouble recalling a good method for solving.

What approach could I take to lead me to an answer?

Comment: Use the quadratic formula.

Comment: How many levels are there? It looks like players will be able to level up very fast after not too long.

Comment: @TheCount: I would say almost the opposite: as the level goes up, the delta in experience goes up; more levels requires more and more experience before you can get to the next level.

Comment: @AdrianKeister you're right, I read it backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find $x=50y^2-50y$ to be the correct formula. Inverting is, as Mike Earnest pointed out in the comments, a matter of the quadratic formula. That is: 
$50y^2-50y-x=0$ implies that
$$y=\frac{50\pm\sqrt{2500+200x}}{100}=\frac{50\pm 10\sqrt{25+2x}}{100}=\frac{5\pm \sqrt{25+2x}}{10}. $$
For this data, we can omit the negative sign to obtain
$$y=\frac{5+ \sqrt{25+2x}}{10}.$$